# android php mysql error

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am a php developer.

Now I learning android.

I want to connect php and android.

I tried many sample codes from internet.

All getting same problem.

"Unfortunately MainActivity has stoped" This is the problem.

Just example: When I submitting login form coming the error message.

All is well, but not connecting to php.

I am going to MAD!

Any extra settings needed in WAMP server?

If you have time, please teach me step by step coding of android in eclipse.
 (Just like file->new->android application project........)That level of teaching.

please teach me a simple login page in android php mysql.

One sample code added below, please tell me problem:

```
 package com.example.listactivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private List nameValuePairs;
private JSONArray jArray;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;


    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/food/food.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //paring data
    int fd_id;
    String fd_name;
    try{
    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject json_data=null;

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            fd_id=json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
            fd_name=json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
    }

    }catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (ParseException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Php code:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("FOOD");
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from FOOD");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Looking your help.

Comment: is ur local file runnig on browswer?

Comment: You have to use IP address 10.0.2.2 for localhost on the emulator, IP address of your computer if using phone - Either way you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for tunneling your localhost to be live. AND IMPORTANT you should be putting Network i/o on the background thread or use AsyncTask.

Comment: First use IP not localhost (10.0.2.2).Second write your code in background instead of main thread.It will work. :)

Comment: Ya adcom, it running fine in browser.

Comment: hi Imran, How can I use code in backgound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 10.0.2.2 for referring php localhost .

Look at this api -->[API](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Here is Your Source Code , Basically needed claenup and main issues was **NetworkONMainThread**

[Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eleh5mwrg7ccavk/VarnaLabDbJson.rar)

Comment: Hi adcom, I used 10.0.22 , 127.0.0 and my system ip. Both get same problem

Comment: its 10.0.2.2 i hv used 10.0.22

Answer (score 0):

First of all, StackOverflow is not a place for asking users to "teach" you something. It is a place for getting help to solve a problem you are already facing with your **existing** code.

Regarding your questions, there are a lot of great tutorials on the Internet for connecting PHP/MySQL to Android. Android Hive's [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) is a well-written one. It covers everything from installing WAMP to writing a fully functional Android application. I suggest that you read it since it is the same exact thing you want.

Off-topic advice: If you really want to learn developing Android apps, you should start by reading a book or watching online tutorials such as Lynda. It is important to understand the basic concepts (such as lifecycles, threads, debugging, ...) before moving on to higher stuff since it will help you understand and solve the issues you might face.

Good Luck.